# R save date and time interval and sequence of date into a list

Tags: r, date, loops

Can anyone please tell me why this doesn't work:

```
a<-list()
b<-as.array(as.Date(c,format="%d%b%Y))

for(i in 1:10){
 for(j in 1:10){
    a[[i]][j]<-min(b)
 }
}
```

Assigning a date, or interval() from lubricate package, seq.Date(), none of these work on a[[i]][j] within a loop. I don't know why.

Just updated:This is the closest example I can give. min(b) will always try to assign a date to the element in a.

My question is, why the assigned a[[i]][j] is a numeric value, not a date object.

I can't format a[[i]][j], but I can format a[[i]] as array of date objects.

Do you guys know why?

Comment: `a[[1]]<-vector()` before you assign with `a[[1]][1]<-as.Date("2001-01-01",origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: Since `b` is defined outside of the loop, aren't you just assigning all the `a[[i]][j]` values to be the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access an element of a list you haven't created:

```
a <- list()
a[[1]]
# Error in a[[1]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

To build a list where the first element is your single date element, you could use:

```
a <- list(as.Date("2001-01-01",origin="1970-01-01"))
a[[1]][1]
# [1] "2001-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway, I can create a list within a loop? I have to create a[[1~10]][1~10] in total 100 dates element, do you know how can I do that?

Comment: If you edit your OP to describe a bit more what you're trying to do, there's probably a better way than using a loop to build this list.

Comment: just edited, as you can see, I can't create a list every single time, do you know how can I assign the date into each element of that list?